# Recursion Method running

Tags: java, class, recursion

I have a question. I am trying to do a recursion question about 5 × 6 = 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 like this for example.
and I am having a trouble to compile.

First Class is as :

[image]

and the Second Class is as:

[image]
any help I will appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: On a side note, please refrain from sharing screenshots of code, paste the relevant section directly into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calculator` method in the recursive call is expected to have the same method signature as its initial definition. You can change the line failing to compile as

```
calculator(number2-1);
```

to

```
calculator(number1, number2-1);
```

Comment: Oooh, okay Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two Problem I can see in your program,

1st is the compilation error which you pasted, is because you are passing only one parameter for method which is expecting two parameter. to solve that change

```
calculator(number2-1);
```

to

```
calculator(number1, number2-1);
```

2nd you have compared second number with 1, because of that last value printed in your log will be 24 instead of 30 when as your numbers are 5,6.
instead of

```
number2>1
```

use

```
number2>0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Assignment2{
public int calculator(int number1,int number2){
    //use math.power insted of recursive
    return Math.pow(number2,number1);
}
}
public class result{
public static void main(String [] args){
   Assignment2 assignment2 = new Assignment2();
   System.out.println(assignment2.calculator(5,6));
}
}
```